# Deploying NextJS to IIS 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, next.js, web-hosting

I have build a NextJS app and ran the command "npm run build" to build the app. Now I have the files in the .next folder.
I need to host the app using IIS (7 or 10) on my own servers. I could not find any resources, even I tried ChatGPT but it is confused and giving conflicted answers!

I am using React 18.2.0 and NextJS 13.3.4.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node.js based web apps can be hosted in a general way, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ but different frameworks (like Nuxt) might require further changes. I didn't write specific things about Next but wouldn't be too hard for you to try.

Comment: Turn out to be just a few simple steps https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs

Answer (score 0):

Please check the blog about how to [Deploy NextJs Application on Window’s IIS Server](https://medium.com/@dipneupane/deploying-nextjs-application-on-windows-iis-server-cabdc22bccf8).

We need to install [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases) and [URLRewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) before setting up the deployment.

And we need web.config file. Like below:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```